# passing data from one page to another in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a view with companies list and i have a view with companies details and i want to view the details of a certain company in the company details view ... but i don't know how to transfer the data of the selected company to the other view .

i tried to send the variables using the route url, that's the only thing i had in mind .

do i need to use a session or use post method or is there an easy way ? thanks .

this is the listing code :

```
<section id="inner_pages">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <?php //die(json_encode($resultas))?>
            <div class="listing_header">
                <h5>{{$resultas[0]->act}} , {{$resultas[0]->scat}} à {{$resultas[0]->sct}} ,  {{ $resultas->total() }} Résultats   </h5>
            </div>  
            
            @foreach($resultas as $Resultas)
            <div class="listview_sidebar show_listing">
                <div class="listing_wrap">
                    <div class="listing_img">
                        <a href="#"><img src="{{URL::asset('assets/images/listing_img4.jpg')}}" alt="image"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="listing_info">
                        <h6><a href="/entreprise_details">{{$Resultas->RS}}</a></h6>
                        <p>{{$Resultas->Descp}}</p>
                        <div class="listing_review_info">   
                            <p><span class="review_score">120 vues</span></p>
                            
                            <p class="listing_map_m"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{$Resultas->sct}} </p>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

and this is the function i am using in the controller to view the listing :

```
public function search(Request $request)
{


    $Activities = activities::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();
    //return view('index') ->with('Activity',$Activity);

    $Sous_Categories = sous_categories::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();
    //return view('index') ->with('SousCategory',$SousCategory);

    $Secteurs = secteurs::select('libelle' , 'id')->get();

    
    $id_secteur = $request->get('secteur');
    $id_sous = $request->get('sub_category');
    $id_act = $request->get('activity');


    if( $id_act!="" && $id_sous!="" && $id_secteur!="" ) // category and sub categroy and secteur selected 
    {
        $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->join('activities','activities.id','=','entreprises.idact')
                         ->join('sous_categories','sous_categories.id','=','entreprises.idSousCat')
                         ->where('entreprises.secteurs_id','=',$id_secteur)
                         ->where('entreprises.idact','=',$id_act)
                         ->where('entreprises.idSousCat','=',$id_sous)
                         ->select(array('entreprises.RS','entreprises.secteurs_id','entreprises.Descp','secteurs.libelle as sct','activities.libelle as act','sous_categories.libelle as scat','entreprises.adresse','entreprises.Tel1','entreprises.Tel2','entreprises.mail',))
                         ->paginate(10);                              
               return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Sous_Categories'=> $Sous_Categories , 'Activities'=> $Activities ]);
               //dd($res);

               
    } 
    
    if( $id_act!="" && $id_sous!="" && $id_secteur=="") // category and sub categroy selected 
    {
        $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->join('activities','activities.id','=','entreprises.idact')
                         ->join('sous_categories','sous_categories.id','=','entreprises.idSousCat')
                         ->where('entreprises.idact','=',$id_act)
                         ->where('entreprises.idSousCat','=',$id_sous)
                         ->select(array('entreprises.RS','entreprises.secteurs_id','entreprises.Descp','secteurs.libelle as sct','activities.libelle as act','sous_categories.libelle as scat','entreprises.adresse','entreprises.Tel1','entreprises.Tel2','entreprises.mail',))
                         ->paginate(10);                              
              return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Sous_Categories'=> $Sous_Categories , 'Activities'=> $Activities ]);
               //dd($res);
    }

    if( $id_act!="" && $id_sous=="" && $id_secteur!="") // category and secteur selected 
    {
        $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->join('activities','activities.id','=','entreprises.idact')
                         ->join('sous_categories','sous_categories.id','=','entreprises.idSousCat')
                         ->where('entreprises.idact','=',$id_act)
                         ->where('entreprises.secteurs_id','=',$id_secteur)
                         ->select(array('entreprises.RS','entreprises.secteurs_id','entreprises.Descp','secteurs.libelle as sct','activities.libelle as act','sous_categories.libelle as scat','entreprises.adresse','entreprises.Tel1','entreprises.Tel2','entreprises.mail',))
                         ->paginate(10);                              
              return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Activities'=> $Activities ]);
              
               //dd($res);
    }
    
    if( $id_act!="" && $id_sous=="" && $id_secteur=="") // only category selected 
    {
        $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->join('activities','activities.id','=','entreprises.idact')
                         ->join('sous_categories','sous_categories.id','=','entreprises.idSousCat')
                         ->where('entreprises.idact','=',$id_act)
                         ->select(array('entreprises.RS','entreprises.secteurs_id','entreprises.Descp','secteurs.libelle as sct','activities.libelle as act','sous_categories.libelle as scat','entreprises.adresse','entreprises.Tel1','entreprises.Tel2','entreprises.mail',))
                         ->paginate(10);                              
               return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Activities'=> $Activities ]);
               //dd($res);
    }


}
```

Comment: are companies and company details already in the database? you only need to pass company ID and retrieve the company details from the database

Comment: @AnuratChapanond yes everything is in the database ... how do i pass the ID please?

Answer (score 0):

**In Blade File:**

```
@foreach($resultas as $Resultas)
  <a href="{{route('companyDetails')/. $Resultas->id}}"> View Details</a>
@endforeach
```

**In Routes:**

```
Route::get('/company-details/{$id}','**ContorllerName**@view')->name('companyDetails');
```

**In Controller:**

```
public function view($id)
{
    $detailsPage = **ModelName**::find($id);
    return view('**DetailsPageName**')->with($detailsPage);
}
```

**In Details Page:**

```
<p>{{$detailsPage->companyName}}</p>
```

Comment: i am getting this error after trying what you said :

[Route: details] [URI: entreprise_details/{$id}] [Missing parameter: $id].

Comment: {{route('companyDetails',$Resultas->id)}}



Route::get('/company-details/{id}','**ContorllerName**@view')->name('companyDetails');

Comment: Do changes. And check again